# Read a particular string from a text

Tags: groovy

Below is the text:

---

request: user removal

AccountId:n34567

Thanks & Regards

Mule

---

I am trying to retrieve the string **AccountId:n34567**

Error:
Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)

code:

```
String adjusted = text.toString().replaceAll("^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+", " ");
System.out.println("******* New Formated Email Bodu ***** :"+adjusted)
String content = (adjusted =~ "AccountId:[0-9]+")[0]
System.out.println("Content :"+content)
```

Comment: I'm no Groovy dev so I can't say how `String content = (adjusted =~ "AccountId:[0-9]+")[0]` is meant to work but assuming you want to get the account id, you might need to add a capturing group to the regex, e.g. `"AccountId:([0-9]+)"`

Comment: Also, your number starts with an `n` in your example, so `[0-9]+` won't match to it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input text is in a variable like so:

```
def text = '''request: user removal

AccountId:n34567

Thanks & Regards

Mule'''
```

Then you can just do this

```
def acct = text.find(~/AccountId:(\S+)/)
```

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character

Answer (score 0):

```
def text = '''request: user removal

AccountId:n34567

Thanks & Regards

Mule'''

def accountIdLine = text.lines().find {it.startsWith('AccountId:')}
if (accountIdLine) {
    def accountId = accountIdLine - 'AccountId:'
    println "the Account ID is $accountId"
} else {
    println 'No Account ID was found'
}
```

Prints:

```
the Account ID is n34567
```